# Angular NGRX cannot pass data to reducer when dispatching action from effect. Got Error - TypeError: Cannot freeze

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx, aws-amplify

I am using Angular NGRX for state management in my angular application. On dispatching login action i receives `CognitoUser` object from my login service as i am using `AWS amplify service`.

When i dispatch LoginSuccess action to pass this object i receives error `TypeError: Cannot freeze`. Login Success action is dispatched but data object is not received in reducer.

Here is my effect code

```
export class LoginEffects {
  login$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(LoginActions.login),
      switchMap((action) =>
        from(this.authService.login(action.username, action.password))
      ),
      catchError((error) => of(LoginActions.loginError(error))),
      map((user) => LoginActions.loginSuccess(user))
   )
  );

  // ... other effects
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}
}
```

However if i assign this response user into another object like this

```
const obj = { ...user };
```

Then i am receiving data in reducer but in case of `CognitoUser` object i am not receiving data in reducer.

How can i pass `CognitoUser` object in reducer?

Comment: I have the same issue, also not using ngrx-store-freeze. Did you make any progress?

Comment: @AndreschSerj my issue was that i was getting data of type `CongnitoUser` object from service. That's why i was not able to pass that data to reducer. 
But if you convet  your data in normal json using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) before passing it to success action than you will be able to access it.

Comment: If you can put that into an answer you can get teh 50 Point Bounty i just set on your question :-)

Comment: Thanks @AndreschSerj. I posted answer with sample code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My issue was that i was getting data of type `CongnitoUser` object from service. That's why i was not able to pass that data to reducer. But if you convet your data in normal json using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` before passing it to success action than you will be able to access it.

So effect code will be like this.

```
login$ = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(LoginActions.login),
  switchMap((action) =>
    from(this.authService.login(action.username, action.password))
  ),
  catchError((error) => of(LoginActions.loginError(error))),
  map((user) => {
     user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));
     LoginActions.loginSuccess(user)
  })
 )
);
```

Answer (score -2):

It appears you are using the `ngrx-store-freeze` package. It causes the error.

There is an open related issue here: https://github.com/brandonroberts/ngrx-store-freeze/issues/17

This package is clearly not maintained so I think you should remove it in your project.

Comment: I am not using this package